# How can I make a single html file AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I need to make an AngularJS app that must have all of it's html in a single page (I'll explain why). I'd like to use ng-route to move through multiple "screens", but all of the html must come from the original page (cannot load anything in the background). One way I could solve this is to swap out everything inside the body tag (with content loaded in script tags as ng-template blocks). Is there another way to do this?

I know that the "static page" requirement is odd, but imagine if I wanted to have an html page that runs offline on multiple platforms. In the offline mode it cannot originate from a server or get additional templates.

**EDIT**
Ok, it looks like I had a bad closure that made the code not work in the single page mode. Anyway, here is the working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="startApp">
<head>
    <title>Hello World, AngularJS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="startapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Inline partials -->
<!-- Page 1 -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/page1.html">
<div>
    <h3>Welcome to STAR Marketing</h3>
    <div>
        <a ng-href="#/page2" >Next Page</a>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
<!-- Page 2 -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/page2.html">
<div>
    <h3>Welcome to the second page</h3>
    <div>
        <a ng-href="#/page1" >Back</a>
    </div>
</div>
</script>
<!-- end of partials -->

    <div id="page-div" ng-view>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

startapp.js

```
var startApp=angular.module('startApp',['ngRoute']);

startApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/page1', {
        templateUrl: '/page1.html',
        controller: 'Page1Controller'
      }).
      when('/page2', {
        templateUrl: '/page2.html',
        controller: 'Page2Controller'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/page1'
      });
  }]);

startApp.controller('Page1Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
}]);

startApp.controller('Page2Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
}]);
```

Comment: You need to do some Angular.js tutorials.

Comment: Even if it's offline it doesn't mean that it couldn't have multiple files.

Comment: I've done plenty of tutorials and they don't cover this scenario. When running a static file the browser security model will not allow angular to background load additional files from the file system. Try in Chrome and you'll see what I mean. So everything has to be inside the original, single, html file.

Comment: I'll post some code to show what I'm talking about.

Comment: @Mark.ewd yes, please, show us that code. Thanks!

Comment: Edited to show the working code.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood well what you want, but I think that what you are looking for [is $templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script).

Like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/tpl.html">
  Content of the template.
</script>
```

In this way you can define all the templates that you want in the same page.

Comment: I'm totally aware of templates and mention that in my question.

Comment: @Mark.ewd I think that you haven't understood my answer, in your question you said: "In the offline mode it cannot originate from a server or get additional templates." But I'm giving you the option to have the templates loaded in the same page, by using the `$templateCache`